# jQuery: why does :contains selector return undefined?

Tags: jquery

I am testing a web application and using jQuery to locate a text containing specific string. This is the function I wrote, however, it doesn't seem to respond. I don't know what the tag of the element is ahead of the time.

```
function get_element_by_text(text) {
    $(document).ready(function (){
        var selector = '*:contains(' + text + ')';
        return $(selector).get(0);
    });
}
```

`get_element_by_text("Unanswered");` returns undefined

Comment: You're matching all elements that contain the text, even the `<html>` tag, which would probably be the first match in the collection

Comment: And remove the document ready handler

Comment: I don't know the tag of the element. I tried -1 as index and it did not return anything.

Comment: Try something like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/uWdDz/**, but it would also match the script tag, as that also contains the text you're searching for etc.

Answer (score 2):

The function `get_element_by_text` is not returning anything, you are having a dom ready handler inside it, the value is returned by that inner function.

So `get_element_by_text` does not return any value thus you are getting undefined as the result.

Try

```
function get_element_by_text(text) {
    var selector = '*:contains(' + text + ')';
    return $(selector).get(0);
}
get_element_by_text("Unanswered");
```

but it will give `html` as the result because of your selector

Comment: this is not what I expected, I guess I need to find the closest parent element which contains the text only.