# jQuery: find the closest element to the selector "*:contains('text')"

Tags: jquery

Building on this question [jQuery: why does :contains selector return undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060041/jquery-why-does-contains-selector-return-undefined/21060299), it simply returns the `<html>` which contains the text and everything else in between.

I use the wildcard selector because I don't know what the closest parent containing the text will look like. How can I find the closest element that contains the text? I am using the `:contains` selector so that I can find the element with text and child text nodes when summed up match the value in the `:contains` argument.

Html:

```
<ul>
    <li class="youarehere"><a id="nav-questions" href="/questions">Questions</a></li>
    <li><a id="nav-tags" href="/tags">Tags</a></li>
    <li><a id="nav-users" href="/users">Users</a></li>
    <li><a id="nav-badges" href="/help/badges">Badges</a></li>
    <li><a id="nav-unanswered" href="/unanswered">Unanswered</a></li>
</ul>
```

Expected: `$("*:contains('Questions Tags Users Badges Unanswered')")` that returns `<ul>`, the closest parent which contains all of the text, instead of `<html>`.

Comment: Can you show us the actual HTML?

Comment: That's a strange string to match, and using the `:contains` pseudo selector with a selector that selects every single element in the DOM seems like a terrible idea.

Comment: Also, if the previous question wasn't answered, why did you accept an answer? Did you see the fiddle I posted in your previous question long before a non working answer was posted ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uWdDz/1/

Comment: @adeneo: when I try the html `<div id="some">te<b>st</b></div>
` and search for the string `test` it doesn't seem to work. from my understanding, doing `div:contains("test")` will return that div, but I don't know ahead of time what the tag will be so I am using *. This unfortunately returns the entire document when I need the nearest parent containing the text, even if part of it belongs to it's descendants.

Comment: @adeneo, I undid the accept in that previous question if someone wants to add a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want closest parent then you need to use proper select method:

```
var parent = $(this).closest(":contains('Questions Tags Users Badges Unanswered'"));
```

Comment: I ran this on the current stackoverflow page, `var parent = $(this).closest(":contains('Questions Tags Users Badges Unanswered')");` returns undefined. `var parent = $(this).closest(":contains('Unanswered')");` also returns undefined.

Comment: @KimJongWoo What value of `this` you are passing there?
And yet method `closest()` in jQuery always returns jQuery wrapper object. `undefined` indicates that you have errors elsewhere, check your code.